# SwiftUI scroll view is off screen

Tags: swiftui

I have a ScrollView HStack:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                //Loads of items in here 
            }
            .frame(minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 70)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .padding([.leading,.trailing])
            .cornerRadius(15)
    }
```

It gives me a view like so:

[image]

Im trying to make the view stay within the screen, so the scroll view is not on the edge on the right hand side like below:

[image]

iv tried getting the width of the device, but that seems to mess up the scroll view, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move some of the modifiers to the `ScrollView` itself:

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack {
        //Loads of items in here
    }
    .frame(minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 70)
    .background(Color.blue)
}
.cornerRadius(15)
.padding([.leading,.trailing])
```

You can add more padding to the items inside the `HStack`, if necessary. Here is an elaborated example:

```swift
private var imageNames: [String] = [
    "tortoise", "lizard", "bird", "fish", "ant", "ladybug", "hare"
]

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(imageNames, id: \.self) { name in
                Image(systemName: name)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .frame(minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 70)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
    .cornerRadius(15)
    .padding(.horizontal)
}
```

[image: Scrollview]